# Interactive GUI convenience functions for matplotlib-like package in QT

Tags: matplotlib, qt4

I have a C++ Qt4 application which reads and organizes various data.  I'd like to produce some plots, mainly polar and 2D intensity plots.  I'd like to give the user some basic functionality via GUI, zoom, changing X-Y range (or polar range), colors, axes labels (pretty much the standard stuff you might find in excel).

I know I can manually create the gui but I had hoped that there would be a convenience function (like in QT where you can pull up a file dialog or the color palette without having to create an entire gui from scratch).  I'd appreciate any suggestions for a matplotlib-like package but for C++.

Comment: mpl expose a QTWidget class (the canvas) that you can embed in a QT application and have a look at the `new_manager_from_figure` methods.  You will probably want to remove the calls to `Gcf`, but that might put you on the right path.  I think the harder thing will be figuring out how to get python running in your c++ program.

Comment: Yes, actually I forgot that matplotlib was purely python.  Therefore I'd like to expand my question to suggestions for other plotting packages similar to matplotlib but in C++

Comment: well, its not _purely_ python, it goes down to the c/c++ layer for some of the heavy lifting but that does not really help here.